# Python fast insert multiple characters into all possible places of string

Tags: python, numpy

I want to insert multiple characters into all possible places of string, my current implementation is using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)) to list all possible places of a string, then converting the string to `numpy` array, calling `numpy.insert`([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)) to insert the characters into the array, finally using `join` to convert inserted string array back to string. Taking inserting 2 characters as example:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
string = "stack"
str_array = np.array(list(string), dtype=str)
characters = np.array(["x", "y"], dtype=str)
new_strings = ["".join(np.insert(str_array, ix, characters)) for ix in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(string)+1), len(characters))]
```

Outputs:

`['xystack', 'xsytack', 'xstyack', 'xstayck', 'xstacyk', 'xstacky', 'sxytack', 'sxtyack', 'sxtayck', 'sxtacyk', 'sxtacky', 'stxyack', 'stxayck', 'stxacyk', 'stxacky', 'staxyck', 'staxcyk', 'staxcky', 'stacxyk', 'stacxky', 'stackxy']`

It seems complicated, but I can't find better way to achieve this if I want to insert any number (e.g., 3) of characters into a string. Did I miss any better and faster way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using numpy, instead of plain python lists? Usually, lists are better for random accesses/replacements. Arrays are superior for numerical, vectorised operations. I cannot check the performance either way, since I get an error running your code: ``IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3``.

Comment: I confirm the same error as @MisterMiyagi

Comment: However, if your code works as expected and you want to improve it, consider posting it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO

Comment: @JanStránský Sorry, I incorrectly input the last line's code. Now I have corrected, should be fine now. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. Consider the CR post

Comment: You say "all possible places", but you don't insert after the 'k'.

Comment: I'm not sure about the CR as I want to find a better way, not to improve current code as I believe this implementation is optimized. As suggested by @MisterMiyagi, I want to seek a better way, other than `numpy` shown here.

Comment: @superbrain Good point. I corrected to `len(string)+1`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```
def mix(s, t, p=''):
  return s and t and mix(s[1:], t, p+s[0]) + mix(s, t[1:], p+t[0]) or [p + s + t]
```

My `p` is the prefix built so far. In each recursive step, I extend it with the first character from `s` or the first character from `t`. Unless one of them doesn't have a character left, in which case I just return the prefix plus whatever *is* left.

Demo:

```
>>> mix('xy', 'stack')
['xystack', 'xsytack', 'xstyack', 'xstayck', 'xstacyk', 'xstacky', 'sxytack',
 'sxtyack', 'sxtayck', 'sxtacyk', 'sxtacky', 'stxyack', 'stxayck', 'stxacyk',
 'stxacky', 'staxyck', 'staxcyk', 'staxcky', 'stacxyk', 'stacxky', 'stackxy']
```

It's about 20 times faster than yours on your example case.

Comment: Great! Test this using `time` module, 50x times faster than mine. Can you explain more about the `return` part? Thanks.

Comment: @Elkan Added some explanation.